# BinarySearch for distance between coordinates

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

How should I use binary search to find if there is a distance between neighbor numbers greater than N in a sorted array? For example:

```
Input: 2 5 8 11 16  
Distance: 4
```

So we should get answer that there is such distance between neighbors. (between 11 and 16)

EDIT: Let me be more clear why I want to do this with binary search.
Assume that the INPUT array comes unsorted. Ex:

```
Input: 11 8 2 16 5
```

Then you should sort the array to see which are the neighbors. So after we have a sorted list isn't it the best way to find the distance with some mutation of binary search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use binary search in the worst case scenario, when all numbers are equally spaced at `N`.

The idea of a binary search and other divide-and-conquer algorithms is that you eliminate roughly half of the remaining range at each step. When all items are spaced at `N`, every range of three or more consecutive items could potentially contain a pair of neighbors with the distance of `> N`, so you cannot eliminate either one of the two sub-ranges under consideration. You will eventually examine every single pair of consecutive items, costing you `O(NumItems)`.

That said, you can probably optimize a general case to do considerably better than `O(NumItems)` because of potential pruning opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

You (well, I) wouldn't: binary search requires a sorted list, and you'll spend more time sorting this list (of pairs of neighboring items, ordered by their distance) than you would just scanning the list.

Comment: Why would you have to do this?  Couldn't there be some other approach based on a modified binary search?

Comment: Binary search requires a sorted list, which you don't have.  And, again, it will take more work to sort the list than just to scan it.

Comment: But you're assuming that this is the only way that binary search can be used here.  I'm fairly confident that you're right and that you can't use binary search here, but I don't see any reason why a binary-search-like algorithm that pared down the array couldn't be used.

Comment: ok, assume that you get the array unsorted. Then you should sort it to understand if there is a bigger than N distance between neighbor coordinates in the array.

Comment: It depends -- if you only have one list to search one time, Scott is right: you might as well search the list as you generate the data. If, however, you might need to search the same list many times, then sorting the distances to support binary search may be worthwhile.

Comment: No, you'd scan to find the LARGEST distance, remember that, and then all "distance greater than N" questions become trivial.  And if you need an example to return (OP didn't), just remember the pair with that distance.

Comment: Scott: if you only want a yes/no answer, that's quite true. Though the OP doesn't say so, I guessed he'd probably want the distance closest to (but larger than) the specified one.